# Delete files not matching a list

Tags: php, cron

So I'm trying to make a simple script, it will have a list of predefined files, search for anything that's not on the list and delete it.

I have this for now

```
<?php
$directory = "/home/user/public_html";
$files = glob($directory . "*.*");

foreach($files as $file)
{

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM files WHERE FileName='$file'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
        unlink($directory . $file);
}
?>
```

However, I'd like to avoid the query so I can run the script more often (there's about 60-70 files, and I want to run this every 20 seconds or so?) so how would I embedd a file list into the php file and check against that instead of database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a trailing `/` twice.. In `glob()` you are giving `/home/user/public_html*.*` as the argument, I think you mean `/home/user/public_html/*.*`.

This is why I bet nothing matches the files in your table.. 
This won't give an error either because the syntax is fine.

Then where you `unlink()` you do this again.. your argument `home/user/public_htmltestfile.html` should be `home/user/public_html/testfile.html`.

I like this syntax style: `"{$directory}/{$file}"` because it's short and more readable. If the **/** is missing, you see it immediately. You can also change it to `$directory . "/" . $file`, it you prefer it. The same goes for one line conditional statements.. So here it comes..

```
<?php
$directory = "/home/user/public_html";
$files = glob("{$directory}/*.*");

foreach($files as $file)
{

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM files WHERE FileName=\"{$file}\";");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
    {
        unlink("{$directory}/{$file}");
    }
}
?>
```

***EDIT:*** You requested recursion. Here it goes..

You need to make a function that you can run once with a path as it's argument. Then you can run that function from inside that function on subdirectories. Like this:

```
<?php

/*
    ListDir list files under directories recursively
    Arguments: 
    $dir        = directory to be scanned
    $recursive  = in how many levels of recursion do you want to search? (0 for none), default: -1 (for "unlimited")

*/

function ListDir($dir, $recursive=-1)
{
    // if recursive == -1 do "unlimited" but that's no good on a live server! so let's say 999 is enough..
    $recursive = ($recursive == -1 ? 999 : $recursive);

    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

    // remove trailing / if it is there and then add it, to make sure there is always just 1 / 
    $dir = rtrim($dir,"/") . "/*";

    // read the directory contents and process each node
    foreach(glob($dir) as $node) 
    {
        // skip hidden files
        if(substr($node,-1) == ".") continue;

        // if $node is a dir and recursive is greater than 0 (meaning not at the last level or disabled)
        if(is_dir($node) && $recursive > 0) 
        {
            // substract 1 of recursive for ever recursion.
            $recursive--;
            // run this same function again on itself, merging the return values with the return array
            $retval = array_merge($retval, ListDir($node, $recursive));
        } 
        // if $node is a file, we add it to the array that will be returned from this function
        elseif(is_file($node)) 
        {
          $retval[] = $node;

          // NOTE: if you want you can do some action here in your case you can unlink($node) if it matches your requirements..

        }
    }
    return $retval;
}

// Output the result
echo "<pre>";
print_r(ListDir("/path/to/dir/",1));
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: The slashes were missing ^^ Does this search include subfolders as well? This is important. Also, since I'm planning to use your slashes combined with an array (want to run it as frequent as possible so I wanna avoid queries) is there a command to list all files (including those in subfolders) in array format? So I don't have to create array in the answer below file by file. Thanks!

Comment: No It would not, I will change the answer for a recursive search.

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks a lot, I'm going to mop this into once code and share it here =)

Comment: But you didn't Sam Fisher :)

Comment: My bad =) I used your code to list/store everything and Jeffmans' to compare it. I can post it if you want, it's just a simple copy/past with small modifications =)

Comment: Correct mate, I'm sorry I forgot to mark it as such, I did that right now. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

If the list is not dynamic, store it in an array:

```
$myFiles = array (
    'some.ext',
    'next.ext',
    'more.ext'
);
$directory = "/home/user/public_html/";
$files = glob($directory . "*.*");

foreach($files as $file)
{
    if (!in_array($file, $myFiles)) {
       unlink($directory . $file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I will be using array as I wanna avoid queries. As soon as I get to know how to list all files as array so I don't have to write them down file by file (there's plenty I guess). Also, what do you think, how often can I run this as a cron job without choking the server? I want to run this as frequent as possible, since the demo version of the system will be public, in case someone decides to drop a shell or something along those lines. Thank you!